# apache beam running locally but unable to read data from csv in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-beam

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

`p = beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions())lines = p | beam.io.ReadFromText('file:///C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/dataflow.csv')`

Apache beam is running locally but is unable to read data from csv.

Comment: what if you remove the _file:///_ part of the String ?

Comment: thanks for the reply i am able to do it now